# PayPal Adaptive Payments and shipping address

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've been struggling with this over the past 5 hours, so let's see if someone can help me out here.

I'm using PayPal's Adaptive Payments for making a Chained Payment (just me and a secondary receiver). The problem is: I can't figure out how to force the buyer to put a shipping address.

Here's how I'm making the calls:

```
$primaryReceiver = new \Receiver();
$primaryReceiver->email = 'primary.receiver@mail.com';
$primaryReceiver->primary = 'true';
$primaryReceiver->paymentType = 'SERVICE';
$primaryReceiver->amount = 100;

$secondaryReceiver = new \Receiver();
$secondaryReceiver->email = 'secondary.receiver@mail.com';
$secondaryReceiver->primary = 'true';
$secondaryReceiver->paymentType = 'GOODS';
$secondaryReceiver->amount = 90;

$receiverList = new \ReceiverList(array($primaryReceiver, $secondaryReceiver));

$payRequest = new \PayRequest(
    new \RequestEnvelope('en_US'),
    'CREATE',
    'http://my.site.url/pay/cancel',
    'USD',
    $receiverList,
    'http://my.site.url/pay/success'
);

// maybe this Pay() call is wrong? should it be some other method?
$paymentResponse = $service->Pay($payRequest);

// setting payment options
$payOptions = new \SetPaymentOptionsRequest(new \RequestEnvelope("en_US"), $paymentResponse->payKey);
$payOptions->senderOptions = new \SenderOptions();
$payOptions->senderOptions->requireShippingAddressSelection = 'true';
$payOptionsResponse = $service->setPaymentOptions($payOptions);
```

The response of the SetPaymentOptionsRequest for the pay key obtained in the Pay() call is success, but when I proceed to the payment, the shipping address is not asked for.

Comment: Did you try true instead of "true"? One is a Boolean, the other is a string. While PHP has loose typing true/false to string is not done for you.

Comment: I'm completely lost on this as well.  Did you get any further?  The PayPal documentation is terrible.  It hints at requiring the shipping address, but only in the embedded payment mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience and got a reply from PayPal support that it is not possible.

This feature only works in the Embedded flow (lightbox or popup instead of redirect). Same with receiverOptions (if you wanted to display additional details about the products). Only displayOptions (for e.g. setting the business name) works after the redirect.

Comment: Wow, that sucks! I've been struggling for the last 3 days trying to get a shipping cost, number of units etc to work... and they say its not even possible??? Well that sucks :/